# Prove a relation of a distance function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, proof-writing, graphing-functions

I had to do an exercise with this function:

$$ d_M:\Bbb C \rightarrow \Bbb R, \quad z \rightarrow \inf\{ |z-w|; w \in M| $$
with $\emptyset \neq M\subset \Bbb C$.
First I proved that this function is Lipshitz.
Now I'm in trouble proving that this relation $$d_M(z)=0 \Leftarrow \Rightarrow z \in M$$ 
holds exactly if $M=\overline {M}$ (the closure).

I already have an intuitive idea, but I don't know how to prove the relation.
If we consider the right direction. If the function outputs $0$ it means $z \in M$, that makes sense, because for every $z$ the infimum will give us $0$ only if the $z$ itself is in $M$ and equal to $w$.

The other way. If $z \in M$ than $d_M(z) =0$ because for every $z$ in $M$ there will be one equal to $w$ (considering $w\in M$).

How would you prove it mathematically?

There would be a last question about drawing the graphs of $d_M$ and $d_{\Bbb C \backslash M}$ in case $M=\{ z \in \Bbb C; |z|\lt1 \}$.
In this last question I can't even imagine how they would be.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $M=\overline{M}$

If $d(x,M)=0$ then $x\in \overline{M}$. So $x \in M$.

Now if $x\in M$. $d(x,M)=inf\{ |x-w|; w \in M|\} \leq |x-x|=0$
so d(x,M)=0

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I can't get the first step you're making, how do you say $x\in \overline{M}$ from that expression?

Comment: The closure of a set can be defined in many equivalent ways. One of these definitions is $\overline{M}=\{x/d(x,M)=0\}$. If you don't want to use this definition, give me your favourite definition of  $\overline{M}$ and I will prove to you that $d(x,M)=0$ implies that $x\in \overline{M}$

Comment: I'm used to think that the closure of $M$ is the set $A$ that satisfy $M \subset A$ and $\Bbb R\backslash A$ is an open set.